# python lxml not showing all content

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape a specific section of a web page, and eventually calculate word frequency. But I am finding it difficult to get the entire text. As far as I understand from looking at the HTML code, my script omits the part of that section that are in a break line but without `<br>` tag. 
My code:

```
import urllib
from lxml import html as LH
import lxml
import requests

scripturl="http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-sopranos&episode=s06e21"
scripthtml=urllib.urlopen(scripturl).read()

scripthtml=requests.get(scripturl)
tree = LH.fromstring(scripthtml.content)
script=tree.xpath('//div[@class="scrolling-script-container"]/text()')
print script
print type(script)
```

This is the output:

> ["\n\n\n\n                \t\t\t         ( radio clicks,        \r           music plays )         \r \r           Disc jockey:          \r
>   New York's classic rock    \r              q104.", '3.', '
>   \r \r           Good morning.', "         \r           I'm jim kerr.",
>   '         \r \r          Coming up              \r

When I iterate the result only the phrases that follow the /r and are followed by a comma or double comma.

```
for res in script:
    print res
```

The output is:

> q104.
>   3.
>              Good morning.
>              I'm jim kerr.

I am not confined to lxml, but because I am rather new, I am less familiar with other methods.

Answer (score 0):

An lxml element has both a text and tail method.  You are searching for text, but if there is am HTML element embedded in the element (br, for example), your search for text will only go as deep as the first text the parser gets from the element's text() method.

try:

```
script = tree.xpath('//div[@class="scrolling-script-container"]')
print join(" ", (script[0].text(), script[0].tail()))
```

Comment: For starters, the xpath expression is invalid, `join` is not how it should be called, `text` and `tail` are not methods..

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But the print won't work, because "script" is a list and not a tree.Is there a different solution for this?

Comment: my apologies, script[0].text, script[0].tail should work

Comment: Thanks for this. Because the Tree.xpath creates a list, the join gives an error, that it isn't defined.
I think I need to simplify it, from the beginning. I need to have as tree the part of the HTML that is in the div class I need.

Answer (score 0):

This was bothering me, I wrote out a solution:

```
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
base_url = "http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-sopranos&episode=s06e21"
resp = requests.get(base_url)
root = etree.parse(StringIO(resp.text), parser)

script = root.xpath('//div[@class="scrolling-script-container"]')
text_list = []

for elem in script:
    print(elem.attrib)
    if hasattr(elem, 'text'):
        text_list.append(elem.text)
    if hasattr(elem, 'tail'):
        text_list.append(elem.tail)

for elem in text_list:
# only gets the first block of text before 
# it encounters a br tag
        print(elem)

for elem in script:
# prints everything 
    for sib in elem.iter():
        print(sib.attrib)
        if hasattr(sib, 'text'):
            print(sib.text)
        if hasattr(sib, 'tail'):
            print(sib.tail)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!
It still disregards all text between two br and prints only those that end with "".
Might it be that the problem is with the HTML code itself? it is funny looking, not aligned. 
Maybe the simplest way is to remove all the BR?

Comment: BeautifulSoup might be more forgiving.  I admit, this is an unusual case, I usually use etree without too much problem.